# Destroy this jQuery plugin on toggle up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hacked together this script which toggles table rows and also adds the Circliful plugin (https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful) to animate some stats once the row is toggled open.
This works well and animates on each row that is toggled.
But if I open a row, close the same row and then re-open it, the stats circles are all messed and it adds another bunch of extra duplicate circles.

So I need to know how to 'end, kill, destroy, unbind' (not sure of terminology) the plugin once the row is toggled closed again. And then start the plugin on re-open.

**Here is the fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/62x36sk3/

```
jQuery(function($) {

      $("td[colspan=4]").find(".toggle").hide();

      $("table").click(function(event) {

            event.stopPropagation();
            var $target = $(event.target);

            if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {

                 $target.slideUp();

            } else {

                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".toggle").slideToggle();
                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".win").circliful();
                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".place").circliful();

            }                    
      });
});
```

Comment: Can you possibly show fiddle example or demo links for us to see.

Comment: Just added the link to the fiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I got for you,  I looked at the plugin you used, it's kinda insteresting but I didn't have time to look for it's function to rebuild  So a simple solution would be to just reconstruct whenever you click the rows.

First you empty the container then call the function again.  Check code below and also check this **[updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62x36sk3/1/)**

I have also change the assignment of the click event, I change it to assign directly to the tr since it have an identifier of `class="info"`   where as to what you used it's assigned to all the elements of your table and it will just lookup for the closest tr.  Nothing much of a different but this is more efficient.

```
$("tr.info").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var $target = $(event.target);

            if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
                 $target.slideUp();
            } else {
                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".toggle").slideToggle();

                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".win").html(''); // empty the contents
                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".win").circliful();

                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".place").html('');  // empty the content
                 $target.closest("tr").next().find(".place").circliful();
            }                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to clear the circliful elements' children before painting.  It works for your sample, Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/62x36sk3/2/ .

Add following code at the top of circliful function.

```
this.empty();
```

But there're some potential issues, some data are not cleared and resize event will be bound multipe times, so a better solution is to implement destroy method in circliful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.circliful = function (options, callback) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            startdegree: 0,
            fgcolor: "#556b2f",
            bgcolor: "#eee",
            fill: false,
            width: 15,
            dimension: 200,
            fontsize: 15,
            percent: 50,
            animationstep: 1.0,
            iconsize: '20px',
            iconcolor: '#999',
            border: 'default',
            complete: null,
            bordersize: 10
        }, options);

    return this.each(function () {

        var customSettings = ["fgcolor", "bgcolor", "fill", "width", "dimension", "fontsize", "animationstep", "endPercent", "icon", "iconcolor", "iconsize", "border", "startdegree", "bordersize"];

        var customSettingsObj = {};
        var icon = '';
        var endPercent = 0;
        var obj = $(this);
        var fill = false;
        var text, info;

        // ADDED
        // ***************************************** 

        // already this instance is ran circleful
        if(obj.hasClass('circliful')){
            return;
        }

        // *****************************************
```